# Save datarow after doing a select?

Tags: .net, ado.net

I have this piece of code.
Lets say the original datatable has 4 rows, but after the select the datarows collection has 2 rows.

I need to be able to set a property in the original datatable.

```
_uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface[x].property = x
```

The problem here is how to know which row index to use?

```
DataTable tempTable = _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Clone();

DataRow[] datarows = _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Select("REFMDossierID = " + refmDossierId);
```

Comment: You posted this question already. Please don't post duplicate questions. Edit the existing question if you need to change it.

Comment: No sir, I have only 2 questions and the other one is completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you iterate in the datarows array and check properties of the DataRow object, I believe there is a RowIndex property.